# (AS2) How to access a symbol from inside a class extends movieclip?

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

I created a movieclip symbol and exported to actionscript, I created the .as file:

```
class BRIQUE extends MovieClip
{ 
  function BRIQUE()
  {
     graphics._x=10;
  }
}
```

"graphics" is an image imported on the stage inside my symbol, but it seems not to be accessible this way (I get an error), nevertheless it works this way in as3 then what is the right way in as2 ?

Thanks

Comment: What does the properties panel say under "instance name" when you select the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in AS3 there is an option in Flash that says something like "automatically declare every instance on stage in my class" so Flash adds the `public var graphics:MovieClip` automatically. i think in AS2 you have to do this manually.

AND please use a different name for the variable - `graphics` is an built-in thing.

```
class BRIQUE extends MovieClip
{
  public var mygraphic:MovieClip

  function BRIQUE()
  {
     mygraphic._x=10;
  }
}
```